# How to remove a residual plot in Jupyter output after displaying a matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to display an animation in Jupyter using Matplotlib. Here is some basic example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)


def update(data):
    line.set_ydata(data)
    return line,


def data_gen():
    while True:
        yield np.random.rand(10)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=100);

from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```

When I run the code for the first time (or after restarting the kernel) I get what I want: [image]

However, when I run the very same code for the second time I get a leftover in the left bottom: [image]

I noticed that when I add `%matplotlib inline` at the top, then I got the bad output even after restarting the kernel. Thus my guess is that I have to set the magic command `%matplotlib` to default at the top each time I create an animation, but I can't even find if `%matplotlib` have a default value.

---

I use Anaconda. Here are my versions:
Conda version: `4.4.10`
Python version: `Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.`
IPython version: `6.2.1`
Jupyter version: `5.4.0`

Comment: I ran your code and don't get the 'left over'.

Comment: @10SecTom When you run it for the second time is it still ok?

Comment: When i opened a new notebook and never included %matplotlib inline or %matplotlib, I dont see the problem. When I add %matplotlib inline, I then see it happen, and even when taken out i%matplotlib inline the issue continues. If you open a new notebook and run the code but never add %matplotlib inline, do you get the issue?

Comment: Information on maplotlib majic: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html

Comment: @10SecTom No, but when I run the same code for the second time or when I plot the second animation in a new cell I get the same bug.

Comment: I ran the same code (no magic) in three cells and then ran all three again, no issue. Someone with more knowledge on it might know the cause.

Comment: Different versions of jupyter?

Comment: @10SecTom I have the issue on the second and third cell, I will add my version to the question

Comment: Note sure its the same issue, but: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/344

Comment: I think it is to do with re-running 'fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))' a second time. If I add %matplotlib inline, but don't run the the animation lines in the cell, I get a plot. If I run the animation lines in a separate cell repeatedly I don't get the 'left over'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I used plt.close() to stop the first (unwanted) plot, and have not seen issues running the animation in a separate cell. I believe the issue is similar to those linked in the comments, jupyter is automatically displaying an unwanted plot for the first two lines - `fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))`. I tired suggestions such as using semicolons at end of lines and a few different magic attempts, but no joy. A more concrete solution will no doubt appear, but for now....

Comment: Perfect! plt.close() fixes this bug. I was trying to use plt.isoff() before, but it retured an error. Thanks a lot. PS. I was trying the semicolon as well.

Comment: :) Doing the same as myself, try fail, try again ... I am not really that up on the matplotlib module, it would be nice to know the exact issue, but glad it got you going again.

Comment: I think jupyter is just too agressively trying to output a plot once is sees one. You may capture the complete output from a cell though `%%capture` (as an alternative to `plt.close()`).